# What exactly is Redis Subscription Channel?

Tags: redis, jedis

So when I create a new Jedis subscription instance, and make my Jedis instance to subscribe to it, I have to specify the channel. What exactly is it? I am assuming that it is a string that will be a url of some other systems [I have an API platform which is supposed to get notified of redid status change].

Jedis nor Redis Subscription page was not specific about what type of String I am curious about channel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string can be any string, not necessarily only URLs. It serves as the Redis channel's name - a unique identifier that both publishers and subscribers use to "connect" to the correct channel - so as long as everybody knows that name they can use that channel.